# Invalid Read of Size 4?

Tags: valgrind

I'm running valgrind on a program, and while the program executes just fine, valgrind reports this:

```
==6542== Invalid read of size 4
==6542==    at 0x8049C6F: Table::removeWebsite(Table&) (Table.cpp:146)
==6542==    by 0x8049768: main (app.cpp:140)
==6542==  Address 0x43f87d4 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==6542==    at 0x402B528: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==6542==    by 0x8049BB0: Table::removeWebsite(Table&) (Table.cpp:124)
==6542==    by 0x8049768: main (app.cpp:140)
```

I'm not entirely sure what is wrong. Here is the code that valgrind is pointing to...

```
bool Table::removeWebsite(Table& parm)
{
    bool flag = false; //flag to show if an item is removed or not
    int OriTableSize = currCapacity;

    for (int index = 0; index < OriTableSize; index++) //search through array list, starting at index
    {
        Node *current = parm.aTable[index]; 
        Node *prev = nullptr;
        while (current != nullptr) //search through linked lists at array[index]
        {
            if (current->data->getRating() == 1) //search ratings for 1
            {
                if (prev == nullptr) //if current is the start of the list
                {
                    if (current->next == nullptr) //if current is the only item in this list
                    {
                        delete current;
                        size--;
                        parm.aTable[index] = nullptr;
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parm.aTable[index] = current->next; //point to the next item in list
                        delete current;
                        size--;
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
                else //reset prev->next pointer to skip current
                {
                    prev->next = current->next;
                    delete current;
                    size--;
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            prev = current;
            current = current->next; //go to next position in linked list
        }
    }

    if (flag == true)//at least one item was removed
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

That "delete current" points to a Node, which has:

```
        struct Node
        {
                Node(const SavedWebsites& parm)
                {
                        data = new SavedWebsites(parm);
                        next = nullptr;
                };
                ~Node()
                {
                    delete data;
                    next = nullptr;
                }

                SavedWebsites *data;
                Node *next;
        };
```

and the data in SavedWebsites has the destructor:

```
//Default Destructor
SavedWebsites::~SavedWebsites()
{
    if (this->topic)
    {
        delete [] this->topic;
        this->topic = nullptr;
    }
    if (this->website)
    {
        delete [] this->website;
        this->website = nullptr;
    }
    if (this->summary)
    {
        delete [] this->summary;
        this->summary = nullptr;
    }
    if (this->review)
    {
        delete [] this->review;
        this->review = nullptr;
    }
    rating = 0;
}
```

*note the items "topic" "website" "summary" and "review" are all created with

```
... = new char[strlen(topic)+1] //(We have to use Cstrings)
```

I'm fairly new to all of this, so any ideas of what may be causing this valgrind invalid read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not indicate which line corresponds to `Table.cpp:146`, but based on the Valgrind output, it looks like the allocation in question represents a `Node` instance because the size of 8 bytes matches (assuming a 32-bit system). The invalid read is triggered by the offset 4 of that instance and a size of 4, so this must correspond to the member `next`.

```
Table.cpp:146:
            current = current->next; //go to next position in linked list
```

In case of a `delete` in the iteration, you access the deleted node `current` afterwards. You also initialize `prev` based on the invalid pointer, so the `next` pointer of the last valid node will not be updated correctly in case of deletes.

Your code seems to work fine (but is not) because its behavior depends on the allocator in use and other allocations. If the allocator were to fill the freed memory with a pattern or if that memory was reused immediately and written to, you'd see a segmentation fault.

To address this issue, I'd defer the `delete`. Before the next iteration, you can then either read the next node and delete the original `current` or update `prev` and read the next node.

```
            bool del = false;
            if (current->data->getRating() == 1) //search ratings for 1
            {
                if (prev == nullptr) //if current is the start of the list
                {
                    if (current->next == nullptr) //if current is the only item in this list
                    {
                        parm.aTable[index] = nullptr;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parm.aTable[index] = current->next; //point to the next item in list
                    }
                    del = true;
                    flag = true;
                }
                else //reset prev->next pointer to skip current
                {
                    prev->next = current->next;
                    del = true
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if (del)
            {
                Node *deletenode = current;
                current = current->next;
                delete deletenode;
                size--;
            }
            else
            {
                prev = current;
                current = current->next; //go to next position in linked list
            }
```

Comment: That was exactly it, @horstr! Yep, after reading your comment, then looking at my code, I was definitely trying to assign the "prev" node as the "current" node after an iteration went through, which was a problem if I deleted the current node before that. I moved the prev assignment to after the if statements and didn't assign it to current if current was to be deleted, and that works great. Valgrind is much happier now. I appreciate your detailed help with this problem of mine!!